# Go custom error types: why return pointer to error?

Tags: go, error-handling

Custom error types allow the caller to inspect the category of error with a type assertion:

```
type MyError struct {
    Message string
}

func (e MyError) Error() string {
    return e.Message
}

func GenerateError() error {
    return MyError{"example text"}
}

func main() {
    err := GenerateError()
    _, ok := err.(MyError)
    fmt.Printf("%t\n", ok)
}
```

prints "true".

However, in all examples I've seen explaining this technique, people don't write the code this way. Instead they pass around *pointers* to the custom error type:

```
type MyError struct {
    Message string
}

func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    return e.Message
}

func GenerateError() error {
    return &MyError{"example text"}
}

func main() {
    err := GenerateError()
    _, ok := err.(*MyError)
    fmt.Printf("%t\n", ok)
}
```

Examples:
[gobyexample.com](https://gobyexample.com/errors), [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@sebdah/go-best-practices-error-handling-2d15e1f0c5ee).

Is there any advantage to the extra indirection? Why is it more common if it's merely more complicated?

Comment: In what way is it more complicated?

Comment: Of course it's nothing oppressive, but you have to remember to take the address of all your errors when you return them. It's just not the first way I would think of setting things up. Am I missing a benefit?

Comment: I think there is no _direct_ benefit, but please think of the imaginary reverse case: if the `Error() string` method—which is the sole method comprising the `error` interface—was defined on a non-pointer type, in order to call that method, you'd need to actually copy the whole value to the method—as its receiver. Since you cannot know the size of user-defined error values, such decision would potentially incur unneeded hidden costs when processing error values.

Comment: You might be tempted to counter this with the point that requiring error values are to be passed by pointer forces them to be heap-allocated most of the time. This is indeed true but then consider that any interface—including `error`—is internally a `struct` containing two pointers—one to the original value, and another one—to its real (called "dynamic") type. So, to return an error value of your custom type as `error`, you need to have a pointer to that value anyway. As follows, with the implemented approach, you lose nothing in 99.9% of the real-world cases.